# Jetpack share buttons double when i`m tryin to relocate them

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook-woocommerce, jetpack

I`m trying to relocate jetpack share buttons with this code in functions.php in child theme:

```
function move_sharing() {
    if ( function_exists( 'sharing_display' ) ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19 );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display', 19 );
    echo sharing_display();
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','move_sharing', 60 );
```

And here is what i got: https://yadi.sk/i/aIWP_mWk3Y79TU

[my website](https://narodnilen.ru/23-fevralya-polotentse-mahrovoe-50h90sm/)

I searched thru many resourced and code is almost identical, but the problem still exist.

Update: I did it with display:none for that div, but its not the answer for the question.

Any help will be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: why are you copying complete function? if you copy complete function, it will display 2 times only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this shortcode ?

use this if it a widget

```
[jpshare]
```

or

use this of you are using inside template

```
<?php do_shortcode('[jpshare]')?>
```